# Dynamically create html elements in view based on the returned json object mvc5

Tags: jquery, html, json, asp.net-mvc-5

Im developing a mvc5 application using codefirst approach. Im returning a json object to a view in this way,

```
public JsonResult FillItem(int mnId, int sbId)
    {
        var db = new KnittingdbContext();

        var x1 = db.ItemTemplates.Where(a => a.MainGroupId == mnId).Where(a => a.SubGruopId == sbId).FirstOrDefault().Atribute1;
        var x2 = db.ItemTemplates.Where(a => a.MainGroupId == mnId).Where(a => a.SubGruopId == sbId).FirstOrDefault().Atribute2;
        var x3 = db.ItemTemplates.Where(a => a.MainGroupId == mnId).Where(a => a.SubGruopId == sbId).FirstOrDefault().Atribute3;

        var y1 = db.AtributeDetails.Where(a => a.AtributeId == x1).Select(a => new
            {
                AtributeDetailId=a.AtributeDetailId,
                AtributeDetail=a.AtDetailVal,
                AtributeName=a.Atribute.AtributeName,
                AtributeType=a.Atribute.AtributeType
            });
        var y2 = db.AtributeDetails.Where(a => a.AtributeId == x2).Select(a => new
        {
            AtributeDetailId = a.AtributeDetailId,
            AtributeDetail = a.AtDetailVal,
            AtributeName = a.Atribute.AtributeName,
            AtributeType = a.Atribute.AtributeType
        }); 
        var y3 = db.AtributeDetails.Where(a => a.AtributeId == x3).Select(a => new
        {
            AtributeDetailId = a.AtributeDetailId,
            AtributeDetail = a.AtDetailVal,
            AtributeName = a.Atribute.AtributeName,
            AtributeType = a.Atribute.AtributeType
        }); 

        var ad = new[] { y1,y2,y3};

        return Json(ad, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

There are 2 tables involved here(for my question). Atribute and AtributeDetail tables which has one to many relationship between them.

I want to generate dropdownlists and textboxes dynamically in my view based on the retuned jason object.

Here 'AtributeDetailId' and 'AtributeDetail' are Value and Text elements of dropdownlists to be generated dynamically.

For AtributeType there are two values in database, 'Text' and 'Select'.

In the view, using jquery i want to loop through the jason object(ad) and after checking each object's(objects in jason object) 'AtributeType' if it is 'Text' then i want to generate a textbox(input)or if it is 'Select' i want to generate a dropdown list. Infront of generated textbox or dropdown list i want to show a label based on the particular 'AtributeName'.Here i have only shown 3 objects. But it is varying in actual.

Im struggling to develop correct jquery for this. Below i have shown the jquery i developed up to now. But it is not complete.

```
    $('#SubGrpId').change(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("FillItem", "Item")', // dont hard code your url's
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: { MnId: $('#MainGrpId').val(), SbId: $(this).val() }, // pass the selected value
        success: function (ad) {
            alert("Im In");
            var s = $('<select/>');
            $.each(ad, function (l, u){
                $.each(u, function (i, itemdt) {
                    $('<option />', { value: itemdt.AtributeDetailId, text: itemdt.AtributeDetail }).appendTo(s);
                })
                s.appendTo('#ss');
            })
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("something wrong");
        }
    });
})
```

It comes to the success function. But it only gives me one ddl and every Atribute Detail get binded to it. Could anyone pls help me to develop correct jquery by checking the condition('Text' or'Select') and generate appropriate
Textboxes and ddls with AtributeName infront of those.

This should be in a way that selected values of ddls and entered value in textboxes can be posted back to server.

Withing view's body i have a div with id 'ss'. I want append every generated textbox and ddl in to that div as child divs.

```
<div id="ss" class="col-md-6">

</div>
```

Hope i presented my question in a clear way. All help appreciate. Thanks in advance!

Let's assume y1's AtributeType is 'Text'. Then y1 will not have items in it(y1 is empty). That means 'AtributeDetailId' and 'AtributeDetail' in object is no use. Let's say y1's 'AtributeName' is "atribute1" then i want to generate a textbox with label infront of it showing "atribute1".

Let's assume y2's 'AtributeType' is 'Select'. Then y2 has items in it. Here 'AtributeDetailId' and 'AtributeDetail' are important. Let's assume y2 list is consist of 5 elements. "aa","bb","cc","dd","ee" and y2's 'AtributeName' is "atribute2" then i should generate a ddl containing those 5 elements with a label infront of it showing  "atribute2".

Let's assume y3's 'AtributeType' is also 'Select'. So there are items in it and it is also a ddl.

Now i have 1 textbox and 2 ddls dynamically generated within the div with id"ss".

And example of the values used for a textbox would be

```
y1 = [
    { AtributeDetailId=null, AtributeDetail=null, AtributeName="atribute1", AtributeType="Text" }
]
```

and an example of the values used for a dropdownlist would be

```
y2 = [
    { AtributeDetailId=1, AtributeDetail="aa", AtributeName="atribute2", AtributeType="select" }, 
    { AtributeDetailId=2, AtributeDetail="bb", AtributeName="atribute2", AtributeType="select" },
    {AtributeDetailId=3, AtributeDetail="cc", AtributeName="atribute2", AtributeType="select" }
]
```

Comment: You have a variable `var s` which is a `<select>` element and you add all options to that. Are you trying to create 3 `<select>` elements, one for `y1`, another for `y2` and another for `y3`?

Comment: Also what do you mean by _generate appropriate Textboxes_? - nowhere in your code do you generate any inputs.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, hey thanks for replying :) no, the number of ddls and input boxes are depend on the 'AtributeType'. If 'AtributeType' is 'Text' then it would be a input box. If it is 'Select' then it would be a ddl. I just posted the jquery here to show my attempt. But it is not complete and it might be wrong. Pls  help me with this..

Comment: Here if the 'AtributeType' is 'Text' then i should generate a textbox which then user can input some text.

Comment: Does not quite make sense since `y1` is a collection of objects. If it contains (say) 3 items and they are all `AtributeType="Text"` then do you want 3 textboxes? If they are all `AtributeType="Select"` do you want one `<select>` with 3 options? And what if 2 are "Text" and 1 is "Select"?

Comment: I think it would be best if you edited your question with and example of the data contained in `y1`, `y2` and `y3` with an indication of what you expect the html to be.

Comment: when i enter values to Atribute table it gives me two options. 'Text' or 'Select'. If i select 'Text' then just Atribute table get updated. Nothing goes to AtributeDetail table. But if i select 'Select' then it gives me a separate box to enter some texts and those list of texts get saved in AtributeDetail table. So for this scenario if y1's AtributeType is 'Select' then it should give me a ddls with values in AtributeDetail table. If it is 'Text' then just a textbox because there are no values in AtributeDetail table for that. if y1 'Select' there would be only 1 ddls If y2 also then 2 ddls.

Comment: Sorry, but then your queries don't make sense. You need to show a sample output of `y1`, `y2` and `y3`

Comment: ok give me few mins. I'll update my question and let you know :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92558/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-isuru).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your data structure, your script needs to be

```
var ss = $('#ss');
$('#SubGrpId').change(function () {
  $.ajax({
    ....
    success: function (ad) {
      $.each(ad, function(l, u) {
        // add the label
        var name = u[0].AtributeName;
        var label = $('<label></label>').text(name).attr('for', name);
        s.append(label);
        if (u[0].AtributeType === 'Text') {
          // There is only one item and its for generating a textbox
          var input = $('<input>').attr({ type: 'text', id: name, name: name });
          ss.append(input);
        } else {
          // Its a select
          var select = $('<select></select>').attr({ id: name, name: name });
          // add each option
          $.each(u, function (i, itemdt) {
            select.append($('<option></option>').val(itemdt.AtributeDetailId).text(itemdt.AtributeDetail));
          })
          ss.append(select);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Side note: You are making 2 extra unnecessary database calls to generate variables `x2` and `x3`. Instead use

```
var x = db.ItemTemplates.Where(a => a.MainGroupId == mnId).Where(a => a.SubGruopId == sbId).FirstOrDefault();
```

and then

```
var y1 = db.AtributeDetails.Where(a => a.AtributeId == x.Atribute1).Select(a => new

var y2 = db.AtributeDetails.Where(a => a.AtributeId == x.Atribute2).Select(a => new
```

etc

**Edit**

You could return objects more directly related to your view by modifying your queries to

```
var x = db.ItemTemplates.Where(a => a.MainGroupId == mnId).Where(a => a.SubGruopId == sbId).FirstOrDefault();
var ids = new List<int>{ x.Atribute1, x.Atribute2, x.Atribute3 };
var y = db.AtributeDetails.Where(a => aids.Contains(a.AtributeId)).GroupBy(a => a.AtributeName).Select(g => new
{
    Name = g.Key,
    Options = g.Where(z => z.AtributeDetailId != null).Select(x => new
    {
        Value = x.AtributeDetailId,
        Text = x.AtributeDetail
    })
});
return Json(y, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

and modify the script to

```
success: function (ad) {
  $.each(ad, function(l, u) {
    // add the label
    var name = u.Name;
    var label = $('<label></label>').text(name).attr('for', name);
    s.append(label);
    if (u.Options.Length == 0) {
      // There is only one item and its for generating a textbox
      var input = $('<input>').attr({ type: 'text', id: name, name: name });
      ss.append(input);
    } else {
      // Its a select
      var select = $('<select></select>').attr({ id: name, name: name });
      // add each option
      $.each(u.Options, function (i, option) {
        select.append($('<option></option>').val(option.Value).text(option.Text));
      })
      ss.append(select);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Refer edit for an alternative which is a bit more efficient and less code in creating your queries.